# Parallel testing TESTNG - Chrome Driver issue?

Tags: java, xml, selenium, testng, selenium-chromedriver

My parallel test works in Firefox and IE however, the chrome driver doesn't even start. Just wondering were I am going wrong. My chrome version is: 47.0.2526.111  and I have the latest chrome driver download. My code and my xml are below.

```
@BeforeClass
      public void beforeTest(String browser) {
         // If the browser is Fire fox, then do this
         DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");

          if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {

              driver = new FirefoxDriver();

          // If browser is IE, then do this   

          }else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")) { 

              // Here I am setting up the path for my IEDriver

              System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C://Selenium-java-maven//workSpace//IEDriverServer.exe");

              driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

              if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){ 

                  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Selenium-java-maven//workSpace//chromedriver.exe");

                  driver = new ChromeDriver();
              }
          } 

          driver.get("http://localhost/2010A15/");

      }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests">

<test name="FirefoxTest">

<parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />

<classes>

<class name="utility1.ParallelLogin" />

</classes>

</test>

<test name="IETest">

<parameter name="browser" value="ie" />

<classes>

<class name="utility1.ParallelLogin" />
</classes>
</test>


<test name="chrome">

<parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />

<classes>

<class name="utility1.ParallelLogin" />
</classes>
</test>
 </suite>
```

Comment: FYI: you don't need double slashes for the forward slashes.  That is something you need to do only with backslashes.  maybe that has something to do with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think as per script provided, if provided browser as chrome, first if condition fails as it is for firefox, then go to else if, here also it fails as here we are cross checking for ie. so no chance to navigate for chrome right?

can try once like below

```
  if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {

         driver = new FirefoxDriver();

     // If browser is IE, then do this   

     }

    if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")) { 

         // Here I am setting up the path for my IEDriver

         System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C://Selenium-java-maven//workSpace//IEDriverServer.exe");

         driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }

         if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){ 

             System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Selenium-java-maven//workSpace//chromedriver.exe");

             driver = new ChromeDriver();
         }
```

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: I've just tried this and it still doesn't work. Firefox and IE both work, however, chrome doesn't start.

Comment: Check above, Thanks.